# Fetching data from related objects (master-detail link) with standard controllers?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple datatable which fetches records from my Service Orders object, I have a Service History table which is linked via forigen key to Service Order ID. I would like to know how I can fetch this data using the standard controller?

It should be noted that there could be many records related to any given Service Order, so I need to get the most recent one (either via ID dsc or Date Created dsc)

**Apex:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" title="My Orders" standardController="Service_Order__c" recordSetVar="orders">
  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
    <apex:define name="body">  

    <h2>My Orders</h2>

    <apex:dataTable value="{!orders}" var="so" width="100%">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!so.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!Status_History__c.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>

    </apex:define>
  </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the datatable as you have started, you just need to assign it to the proper related list name as the value. This is usually the plural version of the object name with `__r` at the end. You can confirm this in the definition of the master-detail field on the Service History object. Your datatable tag will look like

```
<apex:datatable value="{!Service_Order__c.Service_Histories__r}" var="so" >
</apex:datatable>
```

A simpler way: If the Related List defined on your page layout has the columns you need, you can just insert that related list directly into your VF page in place of your datatable:

```
<apex:relatedList list="Service_Histories__r" pageSize="20" />
```

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

Make sure the Related List is defined as sorting by CreatedDate descending on the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idea on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrZ0) to be able to sort using the standard controller, but as of now you would need to use an extension or I also found an example of Javascript sorting on a similar question/answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/sort-order-of-child-records-using-a-standard-controller). Only other workaround, without code, I could think of trying is to rollup the max of created date from the child object and render if child created date = the parent rollup field.

Comment: Ah you bring up a good point that I never actually thought about, the ordering of the list. I may have to opt for a custom approach.