# Order of records retrieved

Tags: quote, visualforce-template, quotelineitem

We have an visualforce email template which display all the Quote line items of the quote in a table format. We use apex:repeat with relatedTo.QuoteLineItems for this. What is the order in which the QuoteLineItems are retrieved? We want it based on CreatedDate but that is not the case. Is it random or is there a specific criteria?

Comment: Take a look at this - [Visual force sort order](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/sort-order-of-child-records-using-a-standard-controller)

Comment: Use a custom component for the QuoteLineItems and then you can control sort order either explicitly in the controller itself or by using a map expression in the `repeat` - VF will sort based on keys in the associated controller's map.

Comment: @TheSalesforceGeneral Thanks. In my case, its a visualforce email template so I dont think Javascript would work.

Comment: @cropredy Custom component seems to be the way; I was checking if there was a way to avoid it.

Comment: CustomComponent is correct solution for this but how do I close this? Should I create my own answer?